# is it possible to wake up a Linux device at a specific time

Tags: linux, power-management, wake-up

I run Debian on an embedded board. I would like to suspend or hibernate the board say at 10 pm and wake it up at 7 am. There is no problem to suspend/hibernate the board by `pmi action suspend`/`hibernate`. But, I wonder if it is possible to schedule the board to wake up at a specific time (maybe by using cron or something else?). If it is the case, could you please explain the all necessary steps that how I can do it?

Please note that, it is possible to wake up an embedded board by using an external interrupt signal or building a simple circuit with a MCU like PIC, timer and relay to set when to wake up the board. But is is **not** what I am asking for. I would like to learn if there is any method on Linux to perform the wake up operation. The board has a WiFi connection and not possible to attach another cable apart from the power cable (please do not write about wake-on-lan).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider what you are asking for. You want a single device, which is powered off, to execute some code at some specific time which turns it on. What would execute that code? What would *make* the device execute that code?

Depending on how deeply asleep the device is, it might be possible by configuring the BIOS to power on the device at a specific time, *if* the BIOS supports such a feature. You'd be fiddling directly with bits in CMOS memory on power-down and hoping that you aren't corrupting anything, but in principle it should be doable, and if you don't need e.g. resilience in the case of a BIOS upgrade, it might even be practical. That still does depend on the device not being fully powered off, however; something has to be monitoring the system real-time clock and executing a power-on sequence when it hits a preselected value. Same with techniques such as Wake on LAN, Wake on Ring etc., which all depend on *something* triggering the power-on event. (Do I get a downvote now for writing about Wake on LAN despite you asking answerers not to...?)

More to the point, what is triggered in ATX (even by a power button press) is a *transition from one power state to another*. The only way to fully shut down an ATX system is to turn off the power supply using the switch at the PSU, or unplugging the power cord. This in contrast to AT PSUs, which actually fully powered down when you turned the computer off because *the power switch was in line with the AC power cord* in the same way ATX PSU power switches (not the computer's power button) are. It doesn't really make any difference though, because whether the system is fully powered down or simply running some kind of loop which waits for the system clock to hit a specific value, there is nothing running the operating system, and the CPU, even if it is powered on (which is an implementation detail of the motherboard and BIOS; they might be using a supplemental, low-powered CPU just for simple tasks like that), won't be running your installed code, so there's no Linux anywhere in sight as far as the CPU is concerned, much less anything like cron.

Bottom line; **I would be exceptionally surprised if what you are asking is doable directly through Linux**, although it *might* be possible by looking at the bigger picture of the surrounding hardware and firmware. The safest bet almost certainly *is* precisely that external trigger, programmed on shutdown to trigger a power-on sequence after a given interval or at a given time (if it has an independent RTC).

Comment: If it's a Dell machine, the newer Dell's offer this in the BIOS. I've tested it with positive results, mass deploying this feature is a different story however.

Comment: @MDMoore313 Do Dell sell "embedded boards" as stated by the OP? I somewhat doubt it. Waking the system up at a particular time through the BIOS isn't exactly a new feature; I *think* (but might of course recall wrong) that my old Pentium II system built around an Intel 440BX motherboard sometime around when the P2 was still fairly new had that feature in the BIOS. That's over ten years ago now.

Comment: My mistake, missed that part. That being said, @angs wanted to wake up from sleep and hibernate. While sleep is possible (its even possible on Windows!), hibernate probably not so much. There's an article [here](http://www.osnews.com/story/24111/Wake_Your_Linux_Up_From_Sleep_for_a_Cron_Job) that involves using the rtc kernel driver to do your bidding. Probably not as neat as OP was hoping, but I'll definitely be keeping it in mind for future endeavors.

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone else who is searching for this, look at the interface for the RTC. On my current system, writing a date in the future to `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` will make the system wake up in the future. For example:

```
# wake up the system in 3 minutes
sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 3 minutes'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"
```

Change the `+ 3 minutes` to `tomorrow 0700` is close to what you want, unless you run the command after midnight...

I found this on [linux.com](https://www.linux.com/learn/docs/672849-wake-up-linux-with-an-rtc-alarm-clock).